# How to change my next boot default in grub

Tags: dual-boot, grub

I have a windows debian dual boot and I use it remotely.  There apparently is no way to change grub when logged into windows.  If I am in linux, I can change grub defaults to windows and reboot.  But when I am in windows I dont have a way to update the script as its in ext4.

So I am thinking of changing grub.conf to change the next default to debian so that even if I get to windows, if I reboot, I am back to debian - in below section:

```
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="2"
fi
```

Has anyone done this?  Any help?  Thanks

Comment: I don't get it. Why not just comment out `GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub` (and regen grub.cfg)?

Comment: How will it help?  I still need to be able to boot into windows.  This is mainly for remote use where in some situations I need to run windows.

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/290458 Also, if your machine has UEFI firmware and your OS installations are in UEFI native mode, you can even just use `efibootmgr` to set the UEFI's BootNext instead.

Comment: For UEFI `BootNext`, you can also have [this](https://github.com/pgaskin/bootnext) on Windows so that you will be able to be like "reboot to Windows from Windows".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the best answer and posting to help others.

grub-reboot [OPTION] MENU_ENTRY

set the default boot entry for GRUB, for the next boot only

Note: I could not find grub2-reboot referenced by some.

Thanks to the developer who thought of it !

Answer (score 0):

I do not think, that is a good idea. This approach will force you into linux every time you restart windows. Even if restart is caused by installing OS updates or something similar.

It would be better to mount ext4 partition into Windows and change the `grub.conf` normally. There are several ways to do the mount.

There are several windows tools and drivers of different quality to read extX partitions, but majority are read-only. The ones which can modify files usually have a "do it on own risk" disclaimer.

Since Windows10, you can use WSL:

```
wsl --mount \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0 --partition 1
```

You would have a new mount inside the wsl: `/mnt/wsl/PHYSICALDRIVE0p1/`. And you can do whatever you need.

Comment: Or just use FAT32 for the `/boot` partition.

Comment: Looks like a good idea but cant seem to get it working.  Get an error "process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process". Though it has not yet been mounted.  Also, script change is good too as I dont mind booting into linux especially because it maybe simpler.

Comment: want to avoid separate partitions just to boot, unless no other solution exists

Comment: Per microsoft doc "At this time, only entire disks can be attached to WSL 2".  So though a possible solution, this wont work for me.  I think the script change seems to be the best solution.  But dont know how default and next_entry is used and what is best to be changed.